# Straight line involving polar form

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

> A variable line $L$ through $P(3,4)$ meets lines $x-y+6=0$ and $x-y+10=0$ at $A$ and $B$. A point $Q$ is on $L$ such that $PQ^2=PA.PB$ . Find locus of $Q$.

Attempt: 
If variable line $L$ makes angle $\theta$ with the axis, equation of Line $ L $ is

$\frac{x-3}{cos \theta}$=$\frac{y-4}{sin \theta}$=$r1,r2$

Where $r1$ and $r2$ are distances from lines $ x-y+6=0$ and $x-y+10=0$.

I have got distances as function of $ \theta$ . After this I am stuck. How will I eliminate this parameter? Please help. If I am proceeding in wrong direction then please suggest an appoach.

Comment: Someone please suggest something I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(it is important do draw a picture to see in particular that the straight lines are parallel).

Let us consider $P$ as the new origin. Doing that, we must operate
a change of coordinates ; the formulas are (old coordinates expressed as functions of the new ones) :

$$\begin{cases}x=X+3\\ y=Y+4\end{cases},$$

Therefore, the equations of lines $(L_1)$ and $(L_2)$ become :

$$\begin{cases}(L_1): & X-Y+5=0 \\ (L_2): & X-Y+9=0\end{cases},$$

Taking $X=r\cos \theta, Y=r\sin \theta$, cartesian equation of $(L_1)$ above becomes polar equation $r\cos \theta-r\sin \theta+5=0$, otherwise said,

$$r=\dfrac{5}{-\cos \theta+\sin \theta}=\dfrac{5}{\sqrt{2}\cos (\theta - 3 \pi/4)}$$

For $(L_2)$ :

$$r=\dfrac{9}{\sqrt{2}\cos (\theta - 3 \pi/4)}$$

Otherwise said, the polar equations of these lines with respect to point $P$ (taken as origin) are of the form :

$$p=PA=\dfrac{p_1}{\cos(\theta-\theta_0)} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ p=PB=\dfrac{p_2}{\cos(\theta-\theta_0)}\tag{1}$$

for $\theta_0=3 \pi/4, \ p_1=\dfrac{5}{\sqrt{2}}, \ p_2=\dfrac{9}{\sqrt{2}}$.

(formulas in (1) are the most classical for the polar equations of straight lines with $r$ taking its minimal value (corresponding to shortest distance points) when the denominator is maximal, i.e. when $\theta=\theta_0$.

Remark : the fact that it is the same $\theta_0$ for both lines means that they are parallel .

Therefore relationship $PQ=\sqrt{PA.PB}$, using (1), gives the polar equation of the locus of point $Q$  (still with $P$ considered a the origin):

> $$p=PQ=\dfrac{\sqrt{p_1p_2}}{\cos(\theta-\theta_0)}\tag{2}$$
>
> which is the equation of a straight line parallel to the initial lines (see remark above) and situated in between  them (but not at equal distance from them).

One can work "backwards" to find a cartesian equation for this locus but it is not at all necessary.

Comment: I had forgotten to make the change of coordinates, but it doesn't affect the reasoning. Now fixed with a slight change for a more rigorous approach.

Comment: Yeah I wanted this approach thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- Write an equation of this line $L$: $$y-4=k(x-3)$$ and calulate it intersection with other two line, you get $A$ and $B$ (as variable points depending on $k$).
- Let $C$ be a mipoint of $AB$ and write an equation of (variable) circle with diameter $AB$. Note that $C$ is on fixed line in the midlle of a given lines.
- Write an equation of (variable) circle with diameter $PC$ and calculate it interesection points with first circle. You get say points $M,N$.
- Calculate angle $\angle CPM =\phi$ and see it is constant, so $C$ maps to $M$ under spiral similarity, so $M$ describe some line $\ell$
- Finally, rotate $M$ for angle $\phi$ to $Q$, so $Q$ describe also some line which is picture of $\ell$ under this rotation (actualy it is parallel to $x-y+10=0$).

Comment: According to you the locus should be a circle

Comment: No the locus isn't at all a circle : it is straight line.

Answer (score 0):

Before proving the particular case you asked, it may be instructive to state a general proposition or theorem:

*Between two parallel lines $ (y=a,y=b) $ if a pencil of rays is drawn through origin then the line of geometric means of extreme intercepts as shown is the parallel straight line $ y= \sqrt{ab}.$*

The proof of the above considers relevant similar triangles from picture below and the locus straight line is marked red.

[image: GM of circle intercepts]

In a longer derivation involving polar coordinates for our situation the locus is *a straight line*

$$ y= m x +a\quad y= m x + b \tag1$$

Translate to $ (h,k) = (3,4) $ ; plug into the first line 
$$ (y-k) = m (x-h) +a $$
and slope of line through origin is $\dfrac{y}{x}=p$. The $x$ coordinate
$$ x= \frac{a+k-m h}{p-m}=\frac{Q}{p-m} \tag2 $$
similarly
$$ y=\frac{Qp}{p-m} \tag3 $$
square and add, take square root
$$ r =Q \frac{\sqrt{1+p^2}}{p-m} \tag4 $$
$p=\tan \theta$ 
$$ r= \frac{Q \sec \theta}{\tan \theta -m}=\frac{Q }{\sin \theta -m \cos \theta} \tag5$$
cross multiply
$$ y-m x=Q = a+k-m h \tag6$$
similarly
$$ y-mx=R = b+k-m h $$
Now convenient to convert to polar form
$$ r_A= Q \frac {\sec \theta}{p-m};\,r_B= R \frac {\sec \theta}{p-m};\tag7 $$
so as to obtain its geometric mean
$$ r= \frac{\sqrt {QR}\,\sec \theta} {p-m} \tag8$$
Calculate Cartesian coordinates
$$ (x,y)=  \frac{\sqrt{QR} (1,p)}{p-m} \tag9 $$
simplifying with $p = \tan \theta = y/x$
$$ y-mx= (mh-k)+ \sqrt{(a+k-mh)(b+k-mh)} $$
$$ y = (m x - C) + \sqrt{(a+C)(b+C)} ,\quad C= ( k-m h)\tag{10} $$

where

$$ (h,k,m)=(3,4,1) $$

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand your answer.

Comment: Sorry.. included  the generality and also conventional geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man